# RegEx for matching 7 digit numbers but not ones with a prefix

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to detect 7 digit numbers from plain text and this is the regular expression I'm using.

```
Regex sevenDigit = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)");
```

Now, I want to be able to match only those 7 digit numbers, that do not begin with a particular prefix. Specifically "usr_id". 
How can I modify this regex to match only those that are not of the form usr_id=1234567 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
Regex sevenDigit = new Regex(@"(?<!usr_id=)\b\d{7}\b");
```

Note also the `\b` word boundaries which are a more elegant way of saying "start of number" and "end of number". They don't match *exactly*  like your `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` lookaround assertions (most notably, they would not allow `1234567` to match within `abc1234567xyz` which your regex *would* allow to match). So if you really need this approach, you could also do

```
Regex sevenDigit = new Regex(@"(?<!\d|usr_id=)\d{7}(?!\d)");
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. And I decided to use your suggestion of using word boundaries rather than my approach. It is, as you said, more elegant. Thanks!!